# Overwrite paragraph button.onclick()

Tags: javascript, html

How can I prevent this from happening when i press the button?

Instead of printing below the other output above, I want it to replace what is already there.

First click:

[image]

Second click:

[image]

Code:

```js
var sq = "";
var outSquare       = document.getElementById("outSquare");
var inSquare        = document.getElementById("inSquare");
var bSquare         = document.getElementById("bSquare");


bSquare.onclick = function () {
    var g = inSquare.value;
    outSquare.innerHTML = square(g);
}

function square(a) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= a; i++ ) {
        
        for (var j = 1; j <= a; j++) {
            sq += "*";
        }
        
    sq += "<br>";
    }
    return sq;
}
```

```html
<p id="outSquare"></p>
    <input id="inSquare" type="number"/>
    <button id="bSquare" type="button"> Print </button>
```

Comment: Move `var sq = "";` to inside the function `square`  - Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialise `sq` inside the function too:

```js
var sq = "";
var outSquare       = document.getElementById("outSquare");
var inSquare        = document.getElementById("inSquare");
var bSquare         = document.getElementById("bSquare");


bSquare.onclick = function () {
    var g = inSquare.value;
    outSquare.innerHTML = square(g);
}

function square(a) {

    sq = ""; // empty this string on click

    for (var i = 1; i <= a; i++ ) {
        
        for (var j = 1; j <= a; j++) {
            sq += "*";
        }
        
    sq += "<br>";
    }
    return sq;
}
```

```html
<p id="outSquare"></p>
    <input id="inSquare" type="number"/>
    <button id="bSquare" type="button"> Print </button>
```

Comment: in square function added stmt sq = "";

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.
OP means?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `sq = '';` inside the function `square(a)`. Doing `sq=""` will re-initialize the value of `sq` to empty for new iteration and will output the desired behaviour.

```js
var sq = "";
var outSquare = document.getElementById("outSquare");
var inSquare = document.getElementById("inSquare");
var bSquare = document.getElementById("bSquare");


bSquare.onclick = function() {
  var g = inSquare.value;
  outSquare.innerHTML = square(g);
}

function square(a) {
  sq = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= a; j++) {
      sq += "*";
    }
    sq += "<br>";
  }
  return sq;
}
```

```html
<p id="outSquare"></p>
<input id="inSquare" type="number" />
<button id="bSquare" type="button"> Print </button>
```

Comment: @mplungjan I did not answer this after 10-20 mins -1 day after it was answered.

Comment: But you are getting the accept - you could have gracefully deleted your answer when you saw the lower repped Aagam had answered before you....

Comment: @mplungjan I did not see that. Sorry. I will make sure I see such answers in future. Thanks for your suggestion